# Language limitation when organizing a meeting with Doodle.com

Tags: doodle.com

I'm organizing an international meeting. I prepare the Doodle in Dutch, but the Doodle link doesn't allow me to tweak the language setting, see example URL:

`doodle.com/agqrgrgrg` (arbitrarily chosen letters)

*How do I present the people, to whom I send the URL, the English language?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People will see your poll in the language that they configured in their browsers as their preferred language (provided that Doodle supports that language). Furthermore, users can always switch to a different language using the appropriate link in the footer:
[image]

Comment: I think the OP is talking about the invite that is being sent out by Doodle, not the viewing of the Doodle poll in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Doodle will send the invite in the language you have chosen on its website, if I'm not mistaken.

**You can opt to send the invite yourself, instead of letting Doodle handle it.** This way, you can send the invitation in any language you desire (or multiple languages), incorporating the Doodle link in the message.
Only downside with this approach is that you lose the 'tracking' functionality of Doodle. I.e. Doodle no longer knows who you invited, and who is missing from poll/meeting.